# Mesosphere form validation call back is not working

Tags: meteor, mesosphere

This is the sample code written in the common.js.Its working both client and server side.Meteor.call not working Please help me.

```
Meteor.methods({
    signupUser: function signupUser(rawData) {           
        Mesosphere.signupForm.validate(rawData, function(errors, callback){
            if(!errors)
{             

                var username = '';
                var password = '';    
                for(var i = 0;i < rawData.length ; i++)
                {
                    var obj = rawData[i];
                    if(i == 0)
                    {
                        username = rawData[i].value;                           
                    }
                    else(i == 1)
                    {
                        password = rawData[i].value;
                    }
                }    
                Meteor.call("ltest", username, password, function (error, luser) 
        {

                    if (luser != 'fail') {

                        Session.set('getuser', luser);
                        Session.set('getusername', luser);
                        alert("Login Successfuly");

                        Router.go('/dashboard');
                    }                       
                });
            }

        });
    }
});
```

How to call back for the signupUser function to client in meteor.

Comment: change this line `signupUser: function signupUser(rawData) {` to this `signupUser:signupUser(rawData) {`, also where is `ltest`? can i see that method?

Comment: yes.ltest: function ltest(username,password, callback){ return username;}

Comment: please try to make a Meteor pad about this issue